# Django : "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 19983: invalid continuation byte" when loading a template

Tags: python, django, templates, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying create a web app using django with python and the jupyter notebook environment. 
I am following the tutorial on djangoproject website : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

When I try to load a template in the views file of my project, I get the following error :

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 19983: invalid continuation byte.
```

Here is the part of the code where I call the file :

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

After some research, I found out that a file : mysite/polls/templates/polls/index_fichiers/themedata.thmx gives me the following message when I try to open it in jupyter :

```
Error ! mysite/polls/templates/polls/index_fichiers/themedata.thmx is not UTF-8 encoded. Saving disabled. See Console for more details.
```

In my console :

```
400 GET /api/contents/polls/templates/polls/index_fichiers/themedata.thmx?type=file&format=text&_=1530244665665 (::1) 4.00ms referer=http://localhost:8888/edit/polls/templates/polls/index_fichiers/themedata.thmx
```

I tried to convert this file in UTF-8 by opening it in a text document and saving it with a UTF-8 encoding, but it still have the same message. I tried to add an argument : encoding='UTF-8' to the get_template fonction, but "encoding" is not a keyword argument for it.
Does someone know what I should try ? Maybe change the encoding parameters of my files ? (but I don't know how to do that)
Thanks !

Comment: The `index_fichiers` folder is suspicious - have you been editing templates in MS Word?  Deleting this folder and its contents may solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Indeed I used Microsoft Word; I've deleted the folder and created a new file index.html with notepad++ and now it's working